# Max of P: $P=\left(\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{(b-a)\sqrt{bc}+(c-b)\sqrt{ca}+(a-c)\sqrt{ab}}{2}$

Tags: inequality

> Find  Max value of P: $$P=\left(\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{(b-a)\sqrt{bc}+(c-b)\sqrt{ca}+(a-c)\sqrt{ab}}{2}$$
> for all non- negative real numbers such that: $a+b+c=1$.

I used: $ab+bc+ca\le\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$. So I guessed $Max=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$

The rest is proving: $\frac{(b-a)\sqrt{bc}+(c-b)\sqrt{ca}+(a-c)\sqrt{ab}}{2}\le0$ but it seems complicated for me.

Is there any help to go on my approach or somthing better? Thanks for your help!

Comment: At least you can try to solve optimization problem.

Comment: Can you tell more?

Comment: do you know about Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Note that your claim of "the rest is proving" is not true. EG Take $ a = 0, b = c = 1/2 $.

Comment: oops, thanks @Calvin Lin. Is there any better way to solve it? Also, where is max value?